# Proper way to chain PostCSS and SASS in rollup

Tags: sass, promise, build-tools, postcss, rollupjs

I'm trying to set up rollup to use both SCSS stylesheets and the Lost grid system, which needs to be parsed through PostCSS. I've verified that the SCSS is being parsed correctly, but the PostCSS processor doesn't seem to have any effect.

According to the [`rollup-plugin-sass` docs](https://github.com/differui/rollup-plugin-sass), I just need to pass in the vanilla JS function to the `processor` option. This works without error, but the generated CSS is no different.

Here's my rollup config, called with `rollup -c config/dev.js`:

```
// Rollup plugins.
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import cjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import globals from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals';
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import sass from 'rollup-plugin-sass';
import postcss from 'postcss';
const postcssProcessor = postcss([require('autoprefixer'), require('lost')]);

export default {
  dest: 'dist/app.js',
  entry: 'src/index.jsx',
  format: 'iife',
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      browser: false,
      main: true
    }),
    sass({
//      processor: postcssProcessor,
      output: 'dist/styles.css'
    }),
    babel({
      babelrc: false,
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      presets: [ 'es2015-rollup', 'stage-0', 'react' ],
      plugins: [ 'external-helpers' ]
    }),
    cjs({
      exclude: 'node_modules/process-es6/**',
      include: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
    globals(),
    replace({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development') })
  ],
  sourceMap: true
};
```

Uncommenting the `processor` line has no effect. It should convert `lost-column` lines to `calc` directives, and add vendor prefixes to CSS properties that require them.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a working config that I use:

```
import sass from 'rollup-plugin-sass'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'
import postcss from 'postcss'

sass({
    processor: css => postcss([autoprefixer])
        .process(css)
        .then(result => result.css)
})
```

Comment: How can i pass option to postcss plugin ?, for example pass browser env to autoprefixer

Comment: please mention the refrence: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-sass#processor

Comment: For anyone who is running into issues with `autoprefixer` you have to invoke it: `postcss( plugins: [ autoprefixer() ], )`

Answer (score 19):

You could also approach it the other way around, by using sass as a pre-processor for `rollup-plugin-postcss`:

```js
import sass from 'node-sass'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'

export default {
  entry: 'src/app.js',
  dest: 'dist/bundle.js',
  format: 'iife',
  sourceMap: true,
  plugins: [
    postcss({
      preprocessor: (content, id) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const result = sass.renderSync({ file: id })
        resolve({ code: result.css.toString() })
      }),
      plugins: [
        autoprefixer
      ],
      sourceMap: true,
      extract: true,
      extensions: ['.sass','.css']
    })
  ]
}
```

Comment: compile sass with this version of rollup-plugin-postcss is not a good option beclouse it used node-sass not official sass (dartsass) and its  roo slow and use python for build and will be deprecated soon

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [rollup-plugin-styles](https://github.com/Anidetrix/rollup-plugin-styles) plugin, which handles various preprocessors, including Sass (using both the deprecated node-sass and the recommended sass), and also has built-in PostCSS support.
This solves both the problem of the author of the question and the issue of passing parameters to the autoprefixer - in the same way as when using WebPack:

```
import styles from 'rollup-plugin-styles';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';

export default {
  plugins: [ // rollup plugins
    styles ({
      plugins: [autoprefixer({/* your options */})], // postcss plugins
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: This is me from the future.  Don't use rollup-plugin-styles anymore.  It was great while it lasted but it's gone stale and does not appear to be actively maintained anymore.